# Changes in Android BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-version

Today I noticed that my debug build broke because the `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` now returns

> 1.6-debug

instead of

> 1.6

which is how it used to work before. Does anyone know if there's any documentation changes around this change?

If you're building the debug variant, it now appends `-debug` when you call `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` which is not the case before.
Regardless of whether it's a release or debug build, the value of `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` is always the same.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplication.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 106
        versionName "1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true //important
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        debuggable true
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true"
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
    }
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: post it as code in question. Don't try to post in comments

Comment: Do you have the buildTypes block?

Comment: `versionNameSuffix "-debug"` you (or someone else) has added this for some reason. That's why you are getting different versionName

Comment: I had this suffix before and never got two different strings for debug and release builds. Only today when updated my dependecies and did a test run is when I noticed my app broke, I guess there's bug fixes in Android studio? Anyways, now we know where the problem is, hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `versionNameSuffix "-debug"` in your `build.gradle` file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ....
        //versionNameSuffix "-debug"
    }
}
```

You can check the [doc](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:versionNameSuffix):

> Version name suffix. **It is appended to the "base" version** name when calculating the final version name for a variant.
>   In case there are product flavor dimensions specified, the final version name suffix will contain the suffix from the default product flavor, followed by the suffix from product flavor of the first dimension, second dimension and so on.

Comment: I had this suffix before and never got two different strings for debug and release builds. Only today when updated my dependecies and did a test run is when I noticed my app broke, I guess there's bug fixes in Android studio? Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

VERSION_NAME is versionName in your build.gradle. Maybe you have multiple build files for different build variants or just append the build variant to your versionName.